# DCT transform in MATLAB

Tags: image, image-compression, dct

I want to find the DCT matrix of a picture. I tested the following code. But I can't see values of DCT matrix. Here is my code:

```
image = image;
[m,n] = size(image);
imvector = reshape(image, m*n, 1);
imdct = dct(imvector);  
imagedct = reshape(imdct,m,n);
imshow(imagedct);
```

Comment: What for is this line `image=image;`?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You are trying to calculate the DCT of a 1D version of a 2D image using `dct(imvector)`.

I think what you actually should do is calculating the 2D DCT of your 2D image using `dct2(image)`.

**2.** The following MathWorks documentation pages are very helpful:

- [Discrete Cosine Transform](https://se.mathworks.com/help/images/discrete-cosine-transform.html)
- [dct2](https://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dct2.html?s_tid=doc_ta)
- [dct](https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dct.html)

**3.** The following code calculates the DCT of a test image:

```
% Load sample image
image = imread('cameraman.tif');

% Normalise image
image = double(image)/255;

% Calculate DCT
imageDct = dct2(image);

% Display the image
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(image)
title('Original image','FontSize',24)

% Display the DCT
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(imageDct)
title('DCT','FontSize',24)
```

**The Figure looks as follows:**
 [image]